# tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'}); not working on POST AJAX

Tags: javascript, php

[Before POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Wl4.png)

Here is my code.

// AJAX code to send data to php file.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_comment.php",
        data: {p_id:p_id,full_name:full_name,email:email,content:content,img:img},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(response) {

            $("#load_comment").load(" #load_comment");

            //put the initial init function here instead
            tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});

        }
    });
```

[After Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOCMP.png)

Comment: So you're saying changing method from `GET` to `POST` hides the bars at the top? Can you try this again? Keep everything as it is but change just the `type` to `GET.

Comment: I tried with GET, still not working

Comment: are you getting a post-back?

Comment: I got this solved

Answer (score 0):

I actually removed text-area from div refresh, and cleared the content of tinymce
using tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');

```
        success: function(response) {
            $("#load_comment").load(" #load_comment");
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
        }
```

This is my actual requirement, however the issue is yet not solved on refresh POST.